# hyphen cannot be used in WiX

Tags: wix

I am creating an .msi installer with WiX and have run into an issue. I cannot use the hyphen (-) in the component or file id. I would have have renamed the files with an underscore if it were possible but unfortunately there are multiple reasons why i can't or am not allowed to do so.

I use the following lines in the .wxs:

```
<Component Id="foo-bar.xsd" Guid="*">
  <File Id="foo-bar.xsd" Source="$(var.MyApplication.TargetDir)" KeyPath="yes" />
</Component>
```

I figured that the components id can be something different and it would not really matter. That would solve only a small part of the issue as renaming the file's id would result in a lot of error messages saying the file cannot be found. Is there a work around for this or is changing the file names the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Component and file ids don't have to match the file name. If you omit the @Id attribute, WiX will use the file name as a default and WiX will automatically replace characters that are illegal in ids.

Comment: Thanks, i thought the file id had to be the same as the file name.